# Elegant way for space efficient unpacking of a vector of pairs in two vectors

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, memory, vector

I have a big vector of `std::pair<std::string,size_t>` elements and I want to unpack it in two vectors using small extra memory overhead (I don't want the memory space occupation doubled, i.e. erasing the vector of pairs after the unpacking) and possibly as fast as possible. The following solution is unacceptably slow:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> string_weight;
get_from_file("mybigfile.txt", string_weight); //it just fills the string_weight vector
//... do stuff...
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::vector<size_t> weights;
for (auto it = string_weight.begin(); it != string_weight.end() ; it = string_weight.erase(it)) {
     strings.push_back(std::move(it->first));
     weights.push_back(std::move(it->second));
}
```

Therefore I tried to modify the previous solution just changing the for loop in the following way:

```
for (auto it = string_weight.begin(), it2 = it; it != string_weight.end() ; it = string_weight.erase(it, it2)) {
        size_t delta = 100000;
        for ( it2 = it ; it2 != string_weight.end() && it2 != it+delta; it2++ ) {
            strings.push_back(std::move(it2->first));
            weights.push_back(std::move(it2->second));
        }
    }
```

This is faster but the completion time is proportional to the value I choose for `delta` and I don't like it. Can you help me giving a solution or pointing out some useful technique?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try a) adding `reserve` calls to the destinations, and b) removing the `erase` (no need for that).

Comment: Add `reserve()` on both destination vectors. Get rid of the `std::move()`.

Comment: Doing that breaks the OP's requirements.

Comment: Why don't I need `erase` or `move`?

Comment: @Murray: Erasing is pure wasted work with zero benefit whatsoever.

Comment: With `erase` your algorithm is slow because complexity is O(N*N), because you erase at the beginning, while a `vector` is slow at erasing at the beginning (requires O(N)), but it's fast at erasing at the end (O(1)).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::vector<std::size_t> weights;

strings.reserve(string_weight.size());
weights.reserve(string_weight.size());

for (auto & p : string_weights)
{
     strings.push_back(std::move(p.first));
     weights.push_back(p.second);
}
```

A few variations:

- pre-construct the weights vector:

  ```
  std::vector<std::size_t> weights(string_weight.size());

  // ...

  weights[i] = string_weights[i].second;
  ```

  This may be better because it avoids repeated size checking, but costs you the initial zeroing out. (This could be avoided with a raw dynamic array, or a non-constructing allocator.)
- pre-construct the strings vector:

  ```
  std::vector<std::string> strings(string_weight.size());

  // ...

  strings[i] = std::move(string_weights[i].first);
  // or
  strings[i].swap(string_weights[i].first);
  ```

  Similarly, this avoids repeated range checking.

Comment: The solution works very well in general, but I have a file that generates a `string_weight` vector of ~40 millions entries. In this case, on my poor memory linux laptop, swap space is getting involved when the unpacking starts and a lot of pain happens...

Comment: @Murray: Can you change the algorithm to write directly to two separate vectors?

Comment: unfortunately I can't :(

Comment: @Murray: Can you change the consumer so it can read from the single vector using two projectors?

Comment: Also, 40M entries is hardly a lot. Assuming 3 words for the string and 1 for the size, that's 32 x 40M bytes, i.e. just over 1GB. That's an entirely havable amount of memory...

Comment: Projections is definitely the way to go if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Removing elements from a `std::vector` doesn't free any memory (that is directly owned by the container itself). Even if it did free up memory (which can be achieved by calling [`shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) after `erase()`) that would still require to temporarily (approximately) double the memory usage, since the reallocation would need to happen similar to how a `std::vector` is resized when it is grown - a new (somewhat smaller) block of memory would need to be allocated, the elements copied to that new area, and only then the old allocation would be released.

So (unless you can replace the source `std::vector` with a `std::deque`) you should forget about lowering the high-watermark memory usage during this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Erasing element in the beginning of `std::vector` is expensive operation. You may use 3 possibilities to speed it up:

1. use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector` for pairs, it has O(1) for deleting element in front
2. clear vector of pairs after loop
3. resize target vectors in advance and copy elements backwards

example:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings( string_weight.size() );
auto tit1 = strings.rbegin();
std::vector<size_t> weights( string_weight.size() );
auto tit2 = weigths.rbegin();
for (auto it = string_weight.rbegin(); string_weight.size(); it++, string_weight.pop_back()) {
     *tit1++ = std::move(it->first);
     *tit2++ = std::move(it->second);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's memory woes. Poping from a vector does not free memory.  Freeing the memory causes a memory spike the OP was hoping to avoid.

Comment: @Yakk provided solution at least not worse than OP used by memory consumption (actually should be better because memory allocated on target vectors at once). I doubt memory usage can be improved without changing data types (and/or algorythm) as shrinking source vector in process most possible would make it worse.

Answer (score 2):

You should first just try moving your content over.  Usually most of the space used by a `std::string` is not within the string itself.

So you simply:

```
template<template<class...>class Tuple, class...Ts>
using vec_of_tup = std::vector<Tuple<Ts...>>;
template<template<class...>class Tuple, class...Ts>
using tup_of_vec = Tuple< std::vector<Ts>... >;

vec_of_tup<std::pair, std::string, std::size_t> in;
tup_of_vec<std::pair, std::string, std::size_t> out;

out.first.reserve(in.size());
out.second.reserve(in.size());

for(auto&& e:in) {
  out.first.push_back( std::move(e.first) );
  out.second.push_back( std::move(e.second) );
}
decltype(in){}.swap(in); // forced clear
```

This does use more peak memory, as both vectors are in existence at the same time.  But data used for the strings (above a certain short size) is not double allocated, as we move it from one container to another.

Only the "bookkeeping" data of the string is kept around twice.

Avoiding that is nearly impossible.  Shrinking the memory used by the source vector requires reallocating a buffer of the new size.  If you do this after copying over K elements to the destination vectors, your memory use directly in the vectors is N+K before.  You have to create a new buffer of size (N-K) to copy the elements over to.  So you are using N+K+N-K = 2N memory.

And if you are using 2N memory, you could just use the above solution and avoid the needless copies.

Your code appears to use about 2.8N memory in the "bookkeeping" part of the string *and* does N^2/K element copies.  It is abysmally bad.

Possibly your problem is you are using `std::vector` for ridiculously large N.  The benefits of `std::vector` start to fade when you are using vector sizes that approach that of the memory available on the system.

An approach might be something like implementing a deque with a controlled block size, instead of the default small one.  Say 10 pages of memory per block.

Now erase from the front/back is efficient, and your memory is reasonably contiguous with one page fault every few thousand element reads instead of pure node based containers with a page fault every element read.  You can move part of the container around without trashing your memory, as when you finish moving a block it is freed.

Your optimization route is fraught, find another one.

This is an initial spike.  It is not exception safe:

```
template<class T, std::size_t block_size_guess = 10*4096>
struct block_vector {
  template<class...Args>
  void emplace_back( Args&&...args ) {
    if (!last_block_used) {
      blocks.emplace_back();
    }
    new( (void*)get_ptr( size() ) ) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    last_block_used = (last_block_used+1)%block_size;
  }
  template<class...Args>
  void emplace_front( Args&&...args ) {
    if (!first_block_unused) {
      blocks.emplace_front();
      first_block_unused = block_size;
    }
    --first_block_unused;
    new( (void*)get_ptr( 0 ) ) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  std::size_t size() const {
    if (last_block_used) // if zero, it means the last block is full
      return blocks.size() * block_size - first_block_unused + last_block_used - block_size;
    else
      return blocks.size() * block_size - first_block_unused;
  }
  T& operator[]( std::size_t i ) { return *get_ptr(i); }
  T const& operator[]( std::size_t i ) const { return *get_ptr(i); }
  // todo: iterators, front(), back(), erase( it, it ), erase( it ), etc.
private:
  enum {
    block_calc = block_size_guess/sizeof(T),
    block_size = block_calc?block_calc:1,
  };
  using raw_block = std::array< std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(T)>, block_size >;
  std::deque<raw_block> blocks;
  std::size_t first_block_unused = 0;
  std::size_t last_block_used = 0;

  using block = std::array< T, block_size >;

  block& get_block( std::size_t b ) {
    return reinterpret_cast<block&>(blocks[b]);
  }
  block const& get_block( std::size_t b ) const {
    return reinterpret_cast<block const&>(blocks[b]);
  }
  static std::size_t outer( std::size_t i ) { return (i+first_block_unused)/block_size; }
  static std::size_t inner( std::size_t i ) { return (i+first_block_unused)%block-size; }
  T* get_ptr( std::size_t i ) {
    return std::addressof( get_block( outer(i) )[ inner(i) ] );
  }
  T const* get_ptr( std::size_t i ) const {
    return std::addressof( get_block( outer(i) )[ inner(i) ] );
  }
};
```

Comment: I've got why my solution is bad, thank you to pointing out. The first solution looks like similiar to the one provided by Kerrek, for the second I need more time & practice with C++. I'm still learning, btw

Comment: If you copied backwards, you could remove elements from the end of a src std::vector.  In theory if you had a std::vector that could use `realloc` under the hood and shrink an existing allocation, instead of allocating a new smaller one and copying, you could release a few pages at a time to the free list.  But in practice all mainstream C++ implementations have `std::vector` that are hampered by `new`/`delete` not providing a try_realloc interface, making it impossible for them to be efficient.

Comment: If you were using POSIX `mmap` /`munmap` to manage memory, this would be an easy problem: just copy forward and `munmap` chunks of pages after you're done reading them.  And count on lazy allocation of the destination to not actually need new physical memory until you write it.  The very weak abstractions in C++ is really frustrating for many things that computers should be able to do efficiently.  (Especially for stuff that could easily just be a fallback where not implemented, like a `try_realloc`) .

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to create new vectors, you may create views. so with [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html), you may do:

```
const auto strings = string_weights | ranges::view::keys;
const auto weights = string_weights | ranges::view::values;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/793910baa0e19d3d)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the harbinger of doom here, but,

If you are memory-constrained, you will need to either:

1. batch-process the file, or
2. if possible, treat the file as a random-access data store.

Unless you `reserve` memory in the destination vectors, they will likely resize a few times while being filled. This will not only *over-allocate* memory but will also *encourage fragmentation* - the enemy of contiguous memory allocation (upon which `std::vector` depends, mandated by the standard).

Additionally, once the initial vector has been populated (even if you did it efficiently by reserving the right amount of space) it will never shrink without calling `shrink_to_fit`. Even then, there is no guarantee that it will shrink. And worse, if it did, while doing so, it would consume more memory during the operation.

Answer (score 0):

**If it weren't for all the levels of abstraction in C++, you could do this in-place**.

None of this is possible for the memory owned by a `std::vector` in C++, of course.  And even in assembly, you'd need a way to tell your memory allocator that your one big allocation is now two smaller allocations.  If you wanted to be *able* to do this in C++, you'd maybe use a union of arrays or something, or placement new to repurpose raw memory you got from an allocator.

I post this just as an illustration of how much it sucks to have levels of abstraction that make efficient code impossible.  (e.g. C++ new/delete doesn't even have a try_realloc that could let `vector` *attempt* to grow or shrink in-place; all the mainstream C++ implementations have a std::vector that always just allocates and copies without even trying to see if there is free address space contiguous with the existing allocation when growing.)  IDK why ISO C++ still hasn't added anything which could allow efficient memory management (besides `std::malloc` / `std::realloc` which aren't compatible with new/delete).

If you want to grow a std::vector without writing the new elements (because you want to `read()` into that memory or something), you need a vector using a custom allocator to not construct the elements.

---

`std::string` can be `std::move`ed, which just boils down to copying the object representation.  And `size_t` is trivially copyable.

Given the size ratios of the pair of objects, calculate the byte offset of the end of the first output array.  e.g. assuming a 32-byte `std::string` (3 pointers plus extra space for inline small strings, like libstdc++ on x86-64 uses), and an 8-byte `size_t`, the ratio is 4:1.  Assuming alignment doesn't require extra padding in each pair, that means the source vector has 40-byte elements.

So for a 10M element source array (400M bytes), the string array will be 10 M elements, 320M bytes, and the size_t array will be 80M bytes.

When we're done, the string array will be the first 320MB of the pair array, and the size_t array will be the next 80MB.  We can calculate ahead of time a pointer to that destination.  The location is *also* the start of a pair that needs to be read before we overwrite that memory

**I'll first explain a 1:1 size ratio of objects in a pair.**

- load 2 pairs, one from the start of the whole, and from the offset where the 2nd array will start.  (i.e. `tmp0 = vec[pos0]; tmp1 = vec[pos1]`)
- store the first member of each tmp pair into the space where the first pair was.
- store the second member of each tmp pair into the space where the second was.

Repeat until done, incrementing positions.  Allocating or touching any new memory for this is a total waste of CPU cycles, and will cause unnecessary memory pressure.  On CPUs with SIMD, these loads and shuffles can be nicely vectorized and hopefully run at near-memcpy speed, and fully benefit from the destination being hot in cache vs. copying to new cold memory.

**For pairs of uneven sizes**, you need to load e.g. 4 pairs from the start for every 1 pair from the middle.  4x 40 = 5x 32, so again we can put the new data back without overwriting anything we haven't read yet.  And in the high part, 1x 40B = 5x 8B.

In C++ you could use a local tmp array and a compiler could still plausibly optimize this into registers for small array sizes.

---

Alternatively, don't create a huge vector of pairs in the first place.  Read from the file in medium-sized chunks (like 8kiB is a good size that fits comfortably into L1d cache) and parse lines into 2 vectors.